# How to find usages using Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have following code:

```
public class MyClass{
   ...
}
```

At same workspace I have following class

```
public class AnotherClass{
   @Autowired
   MyClass myClass;
   ...
}
```

If I click right mouse button on `MyClass`(first mentioned) and select "open call hierarchy" I don't see anything.

How to find this usage in Eclipse?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Right click on Myclass, find references in project|workspace.

Open call hierarchy, open inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: How do I find usages of a non java file in my project ? For example properties files, json files etc ?

Answer (score 89):

PC:

1. Select a word (class name, method name, variable name, etc.)
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

Mac:

1. Select a word (class name, method name, variable name, etc.)
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)

Answer (score 21):

For your case, I think both of (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) and (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) work.

To make it more clear:

- (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) is shortkey for Search->References->workspace
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> is short key for Call hierarchy.

Some other useful short keys like:

- (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) : Search->Declaration->worksapce
- (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>) : Back position
- (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>) : Forward position

Answer (score 5):

Try right-click on `MyClass`and then `References->Workspace`. I think this might be what you're looking for.

Also works on methods, variables etc.

Answer (score 2):

Select the resource (method name, class name ) & right click . You will find a menu  with title '**Open Call Hierarchy**' (shortcut key : alt + Ctrl + H ).
This will enlist all the usage in project.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac, press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, both of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> should work.

For Your Information:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> --> is the short key for Search --> References --> workspace

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> --> is the short key for Call hierarchy.