# How to find all calls to all objects of a class

Tags: java, eclipse

I'd like to find every call to **any method** of **any object** of a **specified Class** in the entire workspace.

I know how to find every call to a specific method and also every call to the constructor of a specific class but not how to find every call to any method.

Comment: Did you tried _Java Search_: `com.example.MyClass.*`, _Search For: Method_ and _Limit To: References_?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there in eclipse way to find usages like in idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25618181/is-there-in-eclipse-way-to-find-usages-like-in-idea)

Comment: Right Click on Class --> References --> Workspace/Project :: This will get you all the functions and variables of the class used elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

Open the ***Outline*** view (*Window > Show View > Outline*), **select all the methods** and **hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>** (what you do to find the calls for single method). This works fine with Eclipse Photon.