# How to precisely detect when a variable changes value using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, variables

There is a possibility to add a watchpoint in the Eclipse, like mentioned e.g. here [How to detect when a variable changes value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575336/how-to-detect-when-a-variable-changes-value)

After invoking the watchpoint, the class which contains watched field is displayed and I am able to see that a setter was called. What I would like to know, is **where exactly**, in which place in the code, the setter(or constructor) was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711954/eclipse-showing-full-call-stack-like-when-it-hits-breakpoint-in-debugger-wit) suggests that there is no such feature.

But beyond that, there is a simply workaround: use eclipse to find all [usages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25618181/is-there-in-eclipse-way-to-find-usages-like-in-idea) of the method/ctor that *sets* the thing you are interested in, and then put break points on each of those.

Alternatively, you could put a test in your code under test, to throw exceptions in certain cases, delivering you a nice stack trace containing the call chain.